# Django: retrieve single object from ManyToMany relation effectively

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, database-optimization

I have a database structure which can be simplified as following (Version and AdditionalInfo not shown since not directly related to my question):

```
class Image(models.Model):    
    file = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='images')
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version, blank=False, null=False)

class ExampleImage(models.Model):
    example = models.ForeignKey('Example', blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, blank=False, null=False)
    additional_info = models.ForeignKey(AdditionalInfo, blank=True, null=True)

class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through=ExampleImage, through_fields=('example', 'image')

    def get_default_image(self):
        try:
            image = self.images.get(version=Version.objects.get(name=DEFAULT_VERSION))
        except Image.DoesNotExist:
             # Get some other image, this happens maybe 1 out of 10
```

Now I have a very common need to query all Example objects along with their default image. Currently, I'm doing somewhat like following:

```
example_list = []
examples = Example.objects.all()

for example in examples:
    example_dict = dict(name=example.name, image=example.get_default_image())
    example_list.append(example_dict)

# Then show example_list in template
```

This approach works but it causes thousands of database queries and takes over one minute to perform which is little too long to download a single web page!

So my question is, what is the right approach to optimize this kind of use case. I could possibly set default_image field for the Example model (and use select_related then, but this makes adding images more complicated), hard code the Version id to get_default_image method (not so flexible), make get_default_image method to cached_property etc. but I'm not exactly sure which approach should be used. I already tried many tricks but nothing seems to help my situation. I should find a solution which allows me to query both example and default image with one big query, rather than doing the work in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Is `DEFAULT_VERSION` a module constant? If so, you can factor out the `version=Version.objects.get(name=DEFAULT_VERSION)` call so you don't have to execute it for every `example in examples`.

You should also be able to work with a custom `Prefetch` object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch . Something along the lines of this (though you'll have to test and tweak yourself):

```
qs = Image.filter(version=Version.objects.get(name=DEFAULT_VERSION))
pref = Prefetch('images', queryset=qs, to_attr='image')
examples = Example.objects.prefetch_related(pref)
```

Ideally of course you'd set `Example.default_image` to a `OneToOneField` so you can retrieve the default images efficiently.

The `cached_property` decorator won't really help you here, because it only caches the property as long as the instance exists. It *does* help if you need to call `instance.get_default_image()` multiple times, but you'll still need to execute `get_default_image` once for each instance that you fetch.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, DEFAULT_VERSION is a module constant. Per my understanding, Django should hit database for it only for the first example and use cached result for the rest of the examples?

I'll check custom Prefetch later today, thanks for your help!

Comment: Django is smart, but not *that* smart. You call `get_default_image` on each model, and that method fetches an object from the DB every time it is executed. There is queryset caching, but only for the same queryset **instance** of a QS, e.g. after iterating over `examples`, calling `examples[0]` will not hit the DB again as long as you're in the same scope. `Model.objects.get()` will always try and fetch an object from the DB.

Comment: Your method indeed works, I'm now able to make it in 4 queries! But there is some issues. First, 'image' is a list, so I need to access it 'image.0.file.url' in a template. Another issue is that default image doesn't exist for each object, in that case, some fallback image should be retrieved (see my get_default_image implementation). My current approach doesn't do that.

Comment: well yes, image will be a queryset because of the prefetch. Maybe change the `to_attr='image'` to `to_attr=images_pref` to make that clear. As for the default image, just write a model Method that uses images_pref, eg return getattr(self, 'images_pref', [DEFAULT_IMAGE])[0]